# WooCommerce jQuery working on pages but not in the popup for same buttom

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

i have a little problem. I found a jQuery code that show what type of the product choose are missing and showing with alert instead of the default one.

So the problem is that our website have a quick form for buy and there is not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(e){
        if ($('#pa_flavor').val() == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Plesea, choose a flavor!");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This is the jquery code that working here - https://www2.4plusnutrition.bg/woman-products/her-bcaa/ and click on "Купи" without selecting a option its show - Please, select a packing!

But if you go here - https://www2.4plusnutrition.bg/amino-acids/ , hover the product and click "Преглед" its open a popup with product information and click on "Купи" its showing the default one message/alert.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('body').on('click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function(e){
        if ($('#pa_flavor').val() == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Plesea, choose a flavor!");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Now its showing the both message, default one and jquery one in both pages. I think 'e.preventDefault();' is not working this way or i dont know. Thanks for help anyway!